# MSBuild targets file doesn't cause outputs to be built, even though inputs are newer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, flex-lexer

I am trying to create a msbuild/VS2010 .targets file for flex, so that I can use .l files in Visual Studio 2010. So far, I have produced this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <LFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.l"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Flex"
          BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
          Inputs="@(LFiles)"
          Outputs="@(LFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).c')"
          Returns="@(LFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).c')">
    <Exec Command="flex.exe &quot;-o%(LFiles.RootDir)%(LFiles.Directory)%(LFiles.Filename).c&quot; &quot;%(LFiles.FullPath)&quot; 2>&amp;1 | sed -e &quot;s/. line \([0-9]\+\)/(\1)/&quot; | sed -e s/\&quot;//g"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I added this file to my project, using the `Build Customizations...` dialog. I then added my .l file, `scan.l`, and built the project - `scan.l` was created in the expected place, suggesting that the file name transformations are working. Next, I added `scan.c` to the project, and built the project again. The generated .c file compiled correctly, and the project linked. So it seems that things are basically working.

My expectation was that Visual Studio would then invoke flex if the .l file changes. The target's `Inputs` attribute includes the .l file, and its `Outputs` attribute includes the .c file, and Visual Studio can check whether the input is newer than the output. But in fact, this doesn't happen. If I just change the .l file and rebuild, Visual Studio tells me everything is up to date.

If I delete the .c file and build the project, the .c file is regenerated, just as I'd expect. But if I just change the .l file and build the project, nothing happens. In fact, in this case, msbuild doesn't even seem to run! If I delete the build log before building, Visual Studio tells me that everything is up to date, and no new build log is produced. This makes it rather hard for me to work out what might be going on.

This is my first go with msbuild, so I am probably doing something wrong. But what?

(N.B. my targets file might fall over with multiple .l files, or suffer from some other flaw(s) unrelated to the dependency checking issue - I am not bothered about any of this at this stage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out the fix, I realised I could create a Visual Studio 2008 project with a .rules file, load it into Visual Studio 2010, let Visual Studio 2010 convert it automatically, and examine the result. So I did that.

To fix the problem, add an XML file with the same base name as the targets file. This one will do for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Build.Framework.XamlTypes;assembly=Microsoft.Build.Framework" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:transformCallback="Microsoft.Cpp.Dev10.ConvertPropertyCallback">
  <ItemType
      Name="Flex"
      DisplayName="Flex" />
  <FileExtension
    Name="*.l"
    ContentType="Flex" />
  <ContentType
    Name="Flex"
    DisplayName="Flex"
    ItemType="Flex" />
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

Next, refer to this file in the `ItemGroup` section. The .targets file is pretty small so here's the new version in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml"></PropertyPageSchema>
    <LFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.l"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Flex"
          BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
          Inputs="@(LFiles)"
          Outputs="@(LFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).c')"
          Returns="@(LFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).c')">
    <Exec Command="flex.exe &quot;-o%(LFiles.RootDir)%(LFiles.Directory)%(LFiles.Filename).c&quot; &quot;%(LFiles.FullPath)&quot; 2>&amp;1 | sed -e &quot;s/. line \([0-9]\+\)/(\1)/&quot; | sed -e s/\&quot;//g"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now reload the project, and visit the properties for the .l file. Select the new `Flex` option from the `Item Type` dropdown. This seems to prod Visual Studio into taking a little more care over the file.